# Javascript form validation onSubmit not triggering

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

please can someone help. this form validation is not triggering.. It's really frustrating me. I'm a PHP developer rather than JS so i'm struggling a bit with this even though it's clearly something very simple. I'm just  trying to validate the form based on the delete box being ticked.

Nothing appears when I click submit. It just submits the form so it must be returning true.

```
function deleteVal(chk) {

    var chk;

    // If the checkbox has been set to delete
    if (chk.checked == "delete") {

        var ok=confirm("You are about to delete the selected images below.\nAre you sure you want to do this?");

        if (ok) {

            // Submit
            return true;

        } else {

            // Don't submit
            return false;

        }

    }

    // Delete box was not ticked so return true and submit form
    return true;

}

</script>

<form action="" method="POST" onSubmit="return deleteVal(delete)">
  <label>Delete images?</label><input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="delete" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you `var chk;` inside `function deleteVal(chk)`? That would make `chk` become `undefined`. Also, `if (chk.checked == "delete")` is incorrect, it should be `if (chk.checked==true)`.

Comment: why are u calling function on onSubmit,just call it on submit button click..it will work...

Comment: thanks for your help both. but why the "why are you" type questions? i'm obviously stuck so thats why i'm doing things this way, because i dont know how to do it correctly hence this post.

for the record neither of your suggestions work. I appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the `checked` value properly like so and see if it is true or false.

```
var chk = document.getElementById('delete');

// If the checkbox is checked
if (chk.checked == true) {
```

Then you do not need to pass a variable to the function, however, you do need to give you checkbox an id.

```
<form action="" method="POST" onSubmit="return deleteVal();">
  <input type="checkbox" name="delete" id="delete"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Tested code - http://pastebin.com/FdWdeSCN

Comment: Thank you very much Wezly. That's perfect - works brilliantly. I knew I was close!! 

Much better than the other answers I got within this post. People asking me "why" I'd done something a certain way when in fact, I was actually doing it correctly.

Thanks again.

Comment: np - just as a note, this solution COULD be simplified further with jQuery.

Comment: How would you do it in JQuery? I use JQuery at home but I'm currently in the office and on certain sites we dont use it... this being one of them

Comment: Your question was about JS so I don't want to spam this comment feed, however, searching for 'jQuery Form Validation' will get you a lot of results - jQuery just handles selectors and forms all a lot neater.